# How can i make the Diagram in R Studio more readable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a Digram in RStudio that uses IMDB Top 250 Movies Database. The x-axis is the Box-office(earnings) and the y-axis is the Writers Name.
Most movies have more than one writer (usually 2 or 3), and when i make a Diagramm with the following code:

```
ggplot(data = movies, aes(x=box_office, y=writers,
                      size=box_office)) + geom_point() + 
labs(x="Einnahmen", y="Writers", title="Einnahmen Nach Writers")
```

The result is the following:
[image]

As you can see it is inefficient and unreadable. How can i modify it so i can include only the top 10 highest earning(box-office) writers?
The diagram should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Try `ggplot(data = dplyr::slice_max(movies, box_office, n = 10), ...)`.